# how to convert bytes to uint256 in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am trying to convert bytes to uint256 in solidity. Here is solidity code,

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract Sample {

    function getValue(bytes memory a) external pure returns(uint256 value) {
        assembly {
            value := mload(add(a, 0x20))
        }
    }
}
```

Then I deployed that code `ganache-cli` I tried calling `getValue` like the following in the truffle console,

```
(await contract.getValue(web3.utils.hexToBytes('0xa'))).toString()
```

I expected value 10 will return. But I am getting the following error,

```
Thrown:
TypeError: param.substring is not a function
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:19
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:49
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:269:15)
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:124:14)
    at runScript (/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:366:1)
    at Console.interpret (/Users/xyz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:381:1)
    at bound (domain.js:419:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:432:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:715:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at REPLServer.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:316:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:693:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:1019:14) {
  hijackedStack: 'TypeError: param.substring is not a function\n' +
```

Help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8):

In solidy 0.8.5 you can do

```
bytes b = ...;
uint256 num = uint256(bytes32(b));
```

Comment: BE CAREFUL!

Use this syntax only when you are sure that the bytes data that you have is <= 32 bytes. Else, converting it to bytes32 will truncate data to 32 bytes and you will not recover the correct integer.

In general, this should be fine for most use cases, because 2 ^ 32 is the integer size one can represent using bytes32. If the integer represented by bytes is bigger than the value 2 ^ 32, then you should worry when converting to bytes32.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast bytes to uint256, since bytes is a dynamically-sized byte array.

If you really need to do this conversion, use bytes32 (or any other fixed sized byte array) instead of bytes and then convert it to uint256 by a simple cast:

```
function two(bytes32 inBytes) pure public returns (uint256 outUint) {
      return uint256(inBytes);
}
```

Comment: Getting same error. I think I am not calling properly from truffle console. I am calling the `sliceUint` method like this `await contract.sliceUint(web3.utils.hexToBytes('0xa'), 0)` from truffle console after making sliceUint method external

Comment: I have updated the answer which works for me. Do let me know if that works for you.